# Is it possible to create a basic car game without Object Oriented programming?

Tags: javascript

For my grade 10 computer science project, me and my partner are creating a car game with html and Javascript (with jquery). Is it possible and feasible to do this without Object Oriented programming, which my teacher tells us that we cannot use?

Comment: It would make no sense at at. Luckily, JavaScript is Object Oriented. You will want to create new instances using the same Constructors or new Object instances repeatedly.

Comment: Your teacher would have to define what specific techniques are off limit.  Somewhat by definition, a "car game" would have a "car" in it which is an object which would have some properties so even coding without using typical object oriented language features would still be object oriented programming.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Good stuff was written before OOP existed. Go to it!

Comment: sure it is definitely possible. I made a similar thing without OOP for my high school project. You just have to make bunch variables for the location of the car and other objects ect

Comment: Possible? Yes. Practical? No. This is a bad question and not what stackoverflow is for. We're here to help people when they have code that doesn't work, and they've tried to figure out why but just can't figure it out.

Comment: Would you mind writing some possible steps we could take to make this game? We're trying to make a track with obstacles that the driver has to dodge..

Comment: lol. The stack overflow users who do other people's homework are the suckers of the community. We can help you debug your own code, but it's up to you to start something first.

Comment: @SasukeRinnegan Given the still alive OOP-cult, its actually an interesting question from a historical perspective. See my answer for a pseudo-code explanation of how it is possible.

Comment: I can't believe how many people seem baffled at the idea of programming without objects? PHP didn't have objects until recently and was quite widely used, ANSI C still doesn't have objects and people still write games in that for the demoscene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, OOP is a relatively new programming paradigm, and while advantageous in some instances, it is by no means the only way to code. The issue comes where one draws the line between and "object" and a "data structure".

Procedural programming pre-dated Object-Oriented Programming, is relatively straight forward and relies on the passing of information through data structures.

Let us assume a very basic two player street racing game, along a straight track with obstacles at random intervals. The velocity of the track is fixed, but the players have a little wiggle room in their acceleration so can control their location comparative to the screen, but can't go off it.

A "car" therefore can be stored in programming logic as a data structure with just 2 components: `X`, `Y`. Likewise with obstacles.

Every game tick:

- the road and obstacles moves under the cars
- the players can input to go up, down, left or right
- obstacles are drawn at the top and removed from the bottom.

Thus, out came can be programmed like so, using one loop:

```
cars = [(0,0),(10,0)]
obstacles = []
games_speed = 10
Game = "on"

WHILE game NOT "over":
   REDRAW ROAD
   FOR car in cars:
      GET INPUT FOR car
      UPDATE car
      DRAW car
   FOR obstacle IN obstacles
      REDRAW obstacles
   FOR car, obstacle IN cars * obstacles
      IF (DETECT_COLLISION car, obstacle)
         GAME = "over"

FUNCTION DETECT_COLLISION (object1, object2)
    // Are the X values within some delta?
    if (ABS(object1[0] - object2[0]) < delta)
       RETURN true
    // Same but for Y values
    if (ABS(object1[1] - object2[1]) < delta)
       RETURN true
    RETURN false
```

Comment: This is very interesting. Appreciate the response!

Comment: @SasukeRinnegan Not a problem. As you may have noticed OOP has been the dominant programming paradigm for at least the last 10-20 years, which is a long time in programming. So finding "pre-OOP" resources can be challenging.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find a non-OOP source, especially a car game, to get some inspiration/how-to from. I'm at a pretty basic level.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do so?

Of course, although you would have to repeat a great amount of code, the main advantage (In this case) of Object Oriented Programming is that you can easily create an arbitrary amount of car instances with slightly differing stats, or the same stats for that matter.

To do so without Object Oriented programming would simply be the same, but with more repetition. Instead of setting up a car object you can just constantly repeat the same code to create several car individual instances, which happen to have the same traits.

All in all, your teacher doing so means you will have to repeat (Copy paste, really) more code, which in the real world is bad practice. But it's very within scope to do so.

Comment: Can you provide evidence that not programming in OOP forces you to duplicate code?

Comment: Can you provide a valid counter example to prove otherwise? 

I can't see how the lack of abstraction on a repetitive instance creation wouldn't lead to longer code.

Comment: A. I didn't make a claim, so the proof isn't on me, but the use of loops and function can make code just as terse as any OOP. OOP has its advantages, shorter code is not one of them - although it could be argued that it is more readable in some instances.